# DB2 3-way Deadlatch

Tags: db2

Encountered 3-Way DeadLatch, it happens when the tcb of the index file is reloaded, want to know what conditions would cause the tcb to be reloaded.

Comment: A PMR is probably the way to find an answer to this.